# Searching in a java arraylist without returning a value

Tags: java, search, arraylist, void

Ive been trying to change my method to a void. But whenever I change it, it always prints out the book name and an error message. How can I change my method to a void?

```
public int displayBookDetails(String bookName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
    Library library = librarys.get(i);
    if (library.returnBookName().equals(bookName)) {
      System.out.println("Index: " + i);   
      System.out.println(library.returnBookName());
      System.out.println(library.authorName());           
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
  System.out.println ("Book name is not valid"); 
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile - you must not have any statements in a method after a `return`. What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to change the method signature return type to `void`? Then you must not use `return`.

Comment: Or do you mean the System.out.println() method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the return statements (and replace the first one by a simple return (no parameter)) too.

```
public void displayBookDetails(String bookName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
    Library library = librarys.get(i);
    if (library.returnBookName().equals(bookName)) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + i);   
        System.out.println(library.returnBookName());
        System.out.println(library.authorName());           
        //removed  return i;
        return;
    }
  }

  // removed return -1;
  System.out.println ("Book name is not valid"); 
}
```

Comment: This will print the book name and the warning like the OP mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, I am sure it will work:

```
public void displayBookDetails(String bookName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
    Library library = librarys.get(i);
    if (library.returnBookName().equals(bookName)) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + i);   
        System.out.println(library.returnBookName());
        System.out.println(library.authorName());           
        return; // modified here
    }
  }
  // modified here
  System.out.println ("Book name is not valid"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably still want to return when you've found the book - that may be what you've missed before:

```
public void displayBookDetails(String bookName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
    Library library = librarys.get(i);
    if (library.returnBookName().equals(bookName)) {
      System.out.println("Index: " + i);   
      System.out.println(library.returnBookName());
      System.out.println(library.authorName());           
      return;
    }
  }
  System.out.println ("Book name is not valid"); 
}
```

Personally I'd probably separate out the "search" from "display":

```
public Library getBookDetails(String bookName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
    Library library = librarys.get(i);
    if (library.returnBookName().equals(bookName)) {
       return library;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

public void displayBookDetails(String bookName) {
  Library bookDetails = getBookDetails(bookName);
  if (bookDetails == null) {
    System.out.println ("Book name is not valid"); 
  } else {
    System.out.println(bookDetails.returnBookName());
    System.out.println(bookDetails.authorName());           
  }
}
```

(Note that there's no such thing as the "index" at this point, of course. If you really need to display that as well, it would need to be part of `Library`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using `return` without a value:

```
    System.out.println(library.authorName());           
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type you are trying to change to void only signifies what is returned by the method. However the method might have different side-effects like I/O, e.g. printing to the console. Unfortunately there is no way to constrain side-effects in Java or most OOP langauges. Functional programming aims at getting rid of all side effects in your functions, so it can be reasoned about the program more easily.